# Problem converting ens domain to 0x eth address

Tags: web3py, infura

```
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'))
ens_address = '0x314159265dd8dbb310642f98f50c066173c1259b'resolver_address = '0x5FfC014343cd971B7eb70732021E26C35B744cc4'name_eth_address = 'bianco.eth'
ens = w3.eth.contract(address=ens_address, abi=[])
resolver = w3.eth.contract(address=resolver_address, abi=[])
resolver_address = ens.functions.resolver(name_eth_address).call()
address = resolver.functions.addr(resolver_address).call()
print(address)
```

I'm trying to get from ens domain to 0x ethereum address, but take this error.

How can I correct this problem?